# How to return the frequent/highest repeated word from a List in C#?

Tags: c#

I have got a `List<>` with 5k words in it.

```
var abc = new List<ClassName>();
```

I want to retrieve the frequent/highest repeated word from `List<>` and return it. Thoughts?

```
 public class Datum
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string pic_large { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: can you show the class definition of `ClassName`

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: `GroupBy` by word, `OrderByDescending` by `Count`, get `First`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get the most popular instance of `Datum` in your `abc` List

```
var mostPopular = abc
  .GroupBy(x => x.name)
  .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
  .First();
```

If you want JUST the `name` value of the most popular append a `Select` on the end

```
var mostPopularName = abc
  .GroupBy(x => x.name)
  .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
  .First()
  .Select(x=> x.name);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = abc
    .GroupBy(x => x.name)
    .OrderByDescending(grouped => grouped.Count())
    .First();
```

That `LINQ` query is taking your list, grouping it by `name` property, so you are getting objects: `name`, `Collection<ClassName>`.

You want to Order them descending by it's `Count` and take `First`